# Can you run Kali Linux 32bit debian on a lenovo thinkpad?

Tags: thinkpad, kali-linux, kernel, x86

Can you run Kali Linux 32bit Debian on a Lenovo ThinkPad

Is it possible to run the full Kali Linux on a Lenovo Thinkpad from 2017

If so then I would certainly appreciate it by you explaining how to make it work.

The current error that I'm getting right now is that the kernel isn't 86x or 64x so it's not compatible for running

Comment: Yes, it is possible to install Kali on a Lenovo ThinkPad. To give you more information we'd need to know the exact model of your Laptop and what exactly you attempted to do while installing Kali. Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1395523/edit) your question with this information. Please also read [this question and all following answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: The general rule is: "If you need help, Kali isn't for you"

Answer (score 0):

Kali Linux is a Linux distribution. It can run on any computer that supports a 32bit OS - which is indeed most computers today. Despite the fact that almost every computer nowadays, especially one from 2017, is 64bit, you can run a 32bit OS on a 64bit system. **However, you cannot do vice versa**.

The steps to installing an OS is far too much for one answer, and you should know by now if you are posting this question. Just grab the right ISO from the Kali website [kali downloads](https://www.kali.org/downloads/), and then burn it to a DVD or to a USB. Boot from the USB and follow the installation.

It appears, from your limited information in your question, that you are confused about the processor notation. x86 means 32bit (and is supported by ALL 32bit and 64bit processors) and x86_64 (commonly referred to as x64) is 64bit. If in doubt, use the 32bit ISO. If you can boot into a live Kali instance from the USB or DVD, you can install it. Again, that's a different matter. Please ask specific questions with what you have taken to remedy the situation so that we may help you further.